# Load a Popup Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a detail component in a popup window. My App.js component contains a List component with list of Item component. When click Item component, I want to show a Detail popup. The togglePopup() function is passed from parent List component to child Item then to Detail. Right now, the popup does not show up. Below is my code:
App.js

```
class App extends Component  {
state={ showPopup: false,
        selectedItem:'',
        Items:[]};
togglePopup=()=> {  
    this.setState({  

   showPopup: !this.state.showPopup  
    });  
}  
 onItemseSelect=(item)=>{
    this.setState({selectedItem:item});
  };

render(){
    const Items=['aa','bb','cc'];
    return(

    <List 
    Items={this.state.Items}
    onItemSelect={this.onItemSelect}
    onClick={this.togglePopup}
    />


{this.state.showPopup ?  
    <Detail  
      item={this.state.selectedItem}
      closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}  
    />  
    : null  
    }  

);
}
}
```

List.js

```
import React  from 'react';
    import Item from './Item';

    const List=({Items,onItemSelect,onClick})=>{
        const renderedList= Items.map(item=>{
        return (
        <Item key={item.ID} item={item} onItemSelect={onItemSelect}   onClick={onClick} />
        );
    })
    return <div>

    {renderedList}</div>
    }

    export default List;
```

Item.js

```
import React from 'react';
    const Item=({item, onItemSelect,onClick})=>{
        return <div  onClick={()=>onItemSelect(item)} >
    <div class="content">
    <div class="header">
     {/*display contents*/}
     <button onClick={onClick}>View More</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    };
    export default Item;
```

Detail.js

```
import React from 'react';

    const Detail=({item,closePopup})=>{
        if (!item){
        return <div>loading</div>
        }

       return (
       <div>
         <p>
         {/*contents here*/}
         </p>

        <button onClick={()=>closePopup}>close me</button>
    </div>);
     };
    export default Detail;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set state to show popup, do this

```
onItemseSelect=(item)=>{
    this.setState({selectedItem:item, showPopup: true}); //make showPopup to true so that popup get displayed
};
```

**Note:** As you are using arrow function, no need to bind `this` here,

```
closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
```

You can change this to,

```
closePopup={this.togglePopup}
```

Another thing is, don't do this,

```
<div  onClick={()=>onItemSelect(item) togglePopup={togglePopup}} > //This is wrong way to call two functions
```

```
<div  onClick={()=> {onItemSelect(item); togglePopup;}} > //This is right way to call two functions
```

**If you call `togglePopup` on every item click, then every time `selectedItem:''` will set item to `blank` and you won't be able to see anything on page**

---

**Side note**: `Detail` is a component and not a `popup`. This component will get display on `App` component after `this.state.showPopup` get `true` value. To show it as `popup` you must use `Modal`.

Comment: Thanks. If I use onClick={this.togglePopup} inside Item component, how to handle two onClick() events? There is already a onClick={()=>onItemSelect(item) ?

Comment: where you want to use two events?

Comment: `togglePopup={togglePopup}` you need to remove this. This is not needed. If you cal this function on every item click, then every time `selectedItem:''` will set item to blank and you won't be able to see anything on page.

Comment: I am trying to add onClick togglePopup event at here but off course this syntax does not work. import React from 'react';
 const Item=({item, onItemSelect,togglePopup})=>{
    return <div  onClick={()=>{onItemSelect(item); togglePopup;}} >
    <div class="content">
    <div class="header">
     {/*display contents*/}
    </div>
    </div>
};
export default Item;

Comment: Don't do this, this will make `selectedItem` blank every time, and you won't be able to see Item on page. See the updated answer.

Comment: I passed onClick() from App.js to List, then to Item, added a button for the onClick event. But it still does not load Detail component.

Comment: Have you removed togglePopup from onclick?

Comment: See my edited code above. I changed onClick={this.togglePopup} and then pass onClick down to the child components.

Comment: the togglePopup is called but now popup window show up. I am referencing to this sample code https://codepen.io/bastianalbers/pen/PWBYvz

Comment: You are right the togglePopup is not necessary. After removing togglePopup, adding css for the Detail component, the popup window shows up with my detail contents. Awsome, Thanks! The only problem now is my List contents are gone after closing the popup window.

Comment: This is because of ` Items:[]` in `setState` of `togglePopup` function. Just remove that line also and your code will work fine.

Comment: No, I removed the Items:[]  from the togglePopup function and the background list still goes blank after closing the Detail popup window. Isn't the togglePopup function supposed only to set showPopup state to true or false and it shouldn't reset other state.